# Portable SQL LocalDB or Express

Tags: sql-server, integration-testing, sql-server-express, localdb

For the testing purpose I need to have SQL Server configured on each dev machine.

So once test suite or case is started SQL Server should be accessible locally.

1. I can not share the common server (this can not be changed)
2. Compact Edition doesn't fit requirements - we have cross-DB queries which are not supported
3. Better not to have any pre-requisites for the dev environment (e.g. install SQL Server Express) - it is not preferable
4. Is there any chance to have portable Express/LocalDB editions? To start it manually before the test and to stop after?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is not related to [tag:c#] at all. Please don't add tags just for adding them.

Comment: However, having SQL Server installed and NOT having SQL Server as a pre-requisite are opposite. You either install it or you don't.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto believe my explanation was not clear. I thought it is pretty clear that question about the DB with tags "integration testing", "C#" should be in the context of using DB during the integration testing with C#. So it is not production environment, but testing. I don't see any problem to have NOT installed SQL Server, but have a portable which can be executed on demand from the test.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of Visual Studio installed you will also have SQL Server LocalDB installed. And it is not a service, but a process that will start on demand from another process.

Comment: I don't want to have pre-requisites. In my integration tests I want to be able to have DB instance per test suite. And not to have centralized DB. That's why I need a portable version, which I can start from C# code - from the test

Comment: @deeptowncitizen that's exactly what this answer states.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a job with similar requirements as yours, they wanted to install the application on several computers but they wanted to process the data locally, use of a remote SQL Server was not an option for them (the files that they wanted to process had some sensitive information).

The best option for me due to the requirements was to use LocalDB 2012 and add it as pre-requisite on the APP installer, is just a matter of a few clicks and boom you have LocalDB 2012 working on that machine (the LocalDB MSI installer it's ~70mb).

Of course i had create the database and stored procedures if the database was not creater yet on that machine, nothing that you cannot when you start the application, hope it helps.

Comment: I believe my explanation was not clear. I need this for the testing purpose only. I need to start portable SQL Server from C# code so I will not have any external dependencies. But on production I'll use a real SQL Server